# Include a text representation of an object (like dput) in a function call for reproducible research

Tags: r, reproducible-research

I have created a shiny app in which a user can load a file and use the object as a function argument. I also print the code to run the function locally (so that I or anyone else could copy and paste to reproduce the result).

What I would like to do is to be able to use something like `dput` but to save the text representation of the loaded object to an object rather than the console. `dput` outputs to the console, but simply returns a copy of it's first argument. I can use `deparse` but it fails when the length of the object exceeds width.cutoff (default 60 and max 500).

The following hacky reproducible example illustrates. In it I use `image` as the example function. In my case I have other functions with more arguments.

```
#create example matrices
m2 <- matrix(1:4,2,2)
m4 <- matrix(1:4,4,4)

#this is what I want to recreate
image(z=m2,col=rainbow(4))
image(z=m4,col=rainbow(4))

#convert the matrices to their text representation
txtm2 <- deparse(m2)
txtm4 <- deparse(m4)

#create a list of arguments
lArgs2 <- list( z=txtm2, col=rainbow(4) )
lArgs4 <- list( z=txtm4, col=rainbow(4) )

#construct arguments list
vArgs2 <- paste0(names(lArgs2),"=",lArgs2,", ")
vArgs4 <- paste0(names(lArgs4),"=",lArgs4,", ")

#remove final comma and space
vArgs2[length(vArgs2)] <- substr(vArgs2[length(vArgs2)],0,nchar(vArgs2[length(vArgs2)])-2)
vArgs4[length(vArgs4)] <- substr(vArgs4[length(vArgs4)],0,nchar(vArgs4[length(vArgs4)])-2)

#create the text function call
cat("image(",vArgs2,")")
cat("image(",vArgs4,")")

#the 1st one when pasted works
image( z=structure(1:4, .Dim = c(2L, 2L)),  col=c("#FF0000FF", "#80FF00FF", "#00FFFFFF", "#8000FFFF") )

#the 2nd one gives an error because the object has been split across multiple lines
image( z=c("structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, ", "2L, 3L, 4L), .Dim = c(4L, 4L))"),  col=c("#FF0000FF", "#80FF00FF", "#00FFFFFF", "#8000FFFF") )

#In an ideal world I would also like it to work when I did this, but maybe that's asking too much
image(z=txtm2,col=rainbow(4))
```

I realise that the way I construct the function call is a hack, but when I looked at it a while ago I couldn't find a better way of doing. Open to any suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: why not use `saveRDS` and `readRDS`?

Comment: Thanks @flodel, but I would like to be able to recreate without the need to share a file.

Answer (score 8):

You can do something like :

```
## an object that you want to recreate
m2 <- matrix(1:4,2,2)
## use capture.output to save structure as a string in a varible
xx <- capture.output(dput(m2))

## recreate the object 
m2_ <- eval(parse(text=xx))
image(z=m2_,col=rainbow(4))
```

Comment: Thanks @agstudy. I was trying to avoid having to use eval(parse(text= because that is something I would need to apply to the first argument but not to others. I did notice that it does cope with the text string being split across multiple elements of a vector. I hadn't come across capture.output, but I see that with dput it splits the string in the same way as deparse.